# Is it possible to encrypt/decrypt a text with aws-encryption-sdk-python and using an asymmetric customer key present in KMS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, encryption, asymmetric

Is it possible to encrypt/decrypt a text using an asymmetric customer key, stored in KMS, passing it to the encrypt and decrypt functions of the aws-encryption-sdk-python? I tried this but could not pass the encryption step, it raises an error:

```
An error ocurred (InvalidKeyUsageException) when calling the GenerateDataKey operation: You cannot generate a data key with an assymetric CMK.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no such way. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/introduction.html):

> The AWS Encryption SDK supports **only symmetric encryption** KMS keys. You cannot use an asymmetric KMS key for encryption or signing in the AWS Encryption SDK.